# Add NOT NULL column with separate DML and DDL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add a new column into an existing table, which has to be `NOT NULL`. It is a foreign key referring to ID of other table and I can't use `default` value.
I did it in couple of steps:

1. add the new column to the table with `NULL` constraint
2. run update scripts to update the new column with correct values for all rows
3. add foreign key constraint
4. change the new column to `NOT NULL`

The issue is that I want to follow a rule we have, that the DDL and DML scripts are separated (for couple of reasons). I can't figure out how to do this. Is there a way how to add a `NOT NULL` column into an existing table in a way that the DDL and DML would be separated?

Comment: Seems simple: step 1 is one script, step 2 is one script, steps 3 and 4 could be one script. It's not clear what "separated" is supposed to mean in this context. If it all has to happen in one atomic step then it would seem the rule needs to be relaxed.

Comment: You posted current steps. Could you post *desired* ones? Doesn't matter it maybe wouldn't really work, but - just to illustrate what you meant by saying that you'd want to have DDL and DML separated. This might help us help you.

Comment: already your  steps are separated! What do you need exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do step 1 and 3 together (if you do not then you risk adding values in step 2 that will not match the constraint).

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD column_name NUMBER(8,0)
      CONSTRAINT table_name__column_name__fk REFERENCES other_table(other_column);
```

You can also do step 4 at the same time if you make the `NOT NULL` constraint `DEFERRABLE`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD column_name NUMBER(8,0)
      CONSTRAINT table_name__column_name__nn NOT NULL DEFERRABLE
      CONSTRAINT table_name__column_name__fk REFERENCES other_table(other_column);
```

Then update the data. For example, you can use a `MERGE` statement to update from a sub-query of pre-generated values:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS new_column_name FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 4 FROM DUAL
) src
ON (dst.id = src.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET column_name = src.new_column_name;
```

Then:

```sql
COMMIT;
```

Which will enforce any `DEFERRABLE` `NOT NULL` constraints.

If you did not make the constraint `DEFERRABLE`
then change the column to `NOT NULL`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
  MODIFY column_name NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL;
```

*db<>fiddle [(not deferrable)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dc5bcb67ef62ca20e367f4f51fde6a4e) [(deferrable)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5484b112b503e918d9ad8fc94c137599)*